# Excel Double Reference in a Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel Sheet called "master", one called "all-names" and one called "table-20-01".

In the master sheet I want to write a formula, that gets a sheetname out of a cell in the "all-names" sheet and that name is for example "table-20-01". I want to use that name to reference a cell in that sheet. According to my research I'm supposed to use the INDIRECT Function for that (for example [Increment Worksheet References](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3619-excel-increment-worksheet-reference.html)

So I thought that I could do something like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & "'all-names'!A1" & "'!$A$1")
```

'all-names'!A1 ==> "table-20-01"

'table-20-01'!$A$1 ==> The value I'm looking for

I use this because I want to create formulas that automatically increment sheet references. And since the sheets are not numbered as simply as sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, but table-20-01, table-20-02, ..., table-20-12, table-21-01, I have the names stored in the sheet "all-names".

Unfortunately I am getting a REF error. Anyone?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the actual reference: `=INDIRECT("'" & 'all-names'!A1 & "'!$A$1")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks a lot. It works now...